# Json how to get value from key with special character - json-simple

Tags: java, json, parsing, json-simple

I cannot get a value from a key, because the key has a `$` in it. Here is the jsonobject:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
String str = "{\"$oid\":\"5168d0e0b280f084c3742800\"}";
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(str);

String oid = (String) obj.get("$oid");
System.out.println("oid: " + oid);
```

However the output is:

```
oid: null
```

How can I deal with the key with a special character `$` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `str` is not being formed properly. You need to escape the quotes. Try this:

```
String str = "{\"$oid\":\"5168d0e0b280f084c3742800\"}";
```

Comment: I am sorry. Actually it works. It is my mistake to got the wrong json object. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This worked. But I did not use JSONParser.

```
    String str = "{\"$oid\":\"5168d0e0b280f084c3742800\"}";
    JSONObject obj;
    try 
    {
        obj = new JSONObject(str);
        String oid = (String) obj.get("$oid");
        System.out.println("oid: " + oid);
        Toast.makeText(this, oid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```